# Spring integration - decorate message on fail

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a process consisting of several webservice-calls, initiated by a JMS-message read by Spring-integration. Since there are no transactions across these WS-calls, I would like to keep track of how far my process has gone, so that steps that are already carried out are skipped when retrying message processing.

Example steps:

1. Retrieve A (get A.id)
2. Create new B for A (using A.id, getting B.id)
3. Create new C for B (using B.id, getting C.id)

Now, if the first attempt fails in step 3, I already have a created a B, and know it's id. So if I want to retry the message, it will skip the second step, and not leave me with an incomplete B.

So, to the question: Is it possible to decorate a JMS-message read by Spring-integration with additional header properties upon message processing failures? If so, how could I do this?

The way it works at the moment:

1. Message is read
2. Some exception is thrown
3. Message processing halts, and ActiveMQ places the message on DLQ

How I would like it to work:

1. Message is read
2. Some exception is thrown
3. The exception is handled, with the result of this handling being an extra header property added to the original message
4. ActiveMQ places the message on DLQ

One thing that might achieve this is the following:

1. Read the message
2. Start processing, wrapped in try-catch
3. On exception, get the extra information from the exception, create a new message based on the original one, add extra info to header and send it directly to the DLQ
4. Swallow the exception so the original message dissappears

This feels kinda hackish though, hopefully there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to generalize without more information about your flow(s) but you could consider adding a custom request handler advice to decorate and/or re-route failed messages. See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

As the other answer says, you can't modify the message but you can build a new one from it.

**EDIT**:

> So, to the question: Is it possible to decorate a JMS-message read by Spring-integration with additional header properties upon message processing failures? If so, how could I do this?

Ahhh... now I think I know what you are asking; no, you can't "decorate" the existing message; you can republish it with additional headers instead of throwing an exception.

You can republish in the advice, or in the error flow.

It might seem like a "hack" to you, but the JMS API provides no mechanism to do what you want.

Comment: I'm considering removing the "what I've tried"-section of my question, since people seem to get caught up with it. It's just added in accordance with the "what have you tried"-demand of SO. Also, I don't think I will get it to work that way. Anyways, I don't think adding behaviour to the endpoint will resolve the issue. I'll update my question with some more details.

Comment: Ended up catching all exceptions, and then on exception recreating the message with the additional headers before placing it directly on DLQ. Not as pretty as I would have wanted, but works.

Answer (score 0):

From the spring [forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/726476-messageheaders-is-immutable):

> To place new header to the MessageHeaders you should use
>   MessageBuilder, because not only headers, but entire Message is
>   immutable.

```
return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader(updateflag, message.getHeaders().get("Lgg_Rid") == "ACK" ? "CONF" : "FAIL").build();
```

In an asynchronous context, errors will go to an error channel - either one you configure yourself and indicate in the message headers with `errorChannel`, or a global error channel if none is specified. See for more details [here](http://xpadro.blogspot.fr/2013/11/how-error-handling-works-in-spring.html).

Comment: An error gotten on something that I don't even know if is the correct way of approaching my actual problem.

Comment: I have used that guide for creating my error handler, but I actually don't think it's the way to go, since it's not the original message. I'm using ActiveMQ, and with the default error handling, the message in question is placed on a DLQ. It is this message I would like to mutate, not the intermediate error-message.